# how to cancel DoWork in Backgroundworker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, cancellation

i know this's not the first question about Canceling BackGroundWorker but i didn't find the answer to solve my problem.
i have a method that sends file .. im using backgroundworker to call it ..
So how can i cancel backgroundworker in the middle of sending the file .. i mean where should i put

```
if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending == true)
   {
       e.Cancel = true;
       break;
   }
```

here's the code :

```
 private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        List<object> job = (List<object>)e.Argument;
        string srcPath = (string)job[0];
        string destPath = (string)job[1];
        SendFile(srcPath, destPath);
    }
```

Send Method :

```
 private void SendFile(string srcPath, string destPath)
    {
        string dest = Path.Combine(destPath, Path.GetFileName(srcPath));
        using (fs = new FileStream(srcPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            try
            {
                long fileSize = fs.Length;
                if (sizeAll == 0)
                    sizeAll = fileSize;
                sum = 0;
                int count = 0;
                data = new byte[packetSize];
                SendCommand("receive<" + dest + "<" + fs.Length.ToString());
                ProgressLabel(++fileCount, allFileCount);
                InfoLabel("Sending " + srcPath, "busy");
                while (sum < fileSize)
                {
                    count = fs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    network.Write(data, 0, count);
                    sum += count;
                    sumAll += count;
                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)((sum * 100) / fileSize));
                }
                network.Flush();
            }
            finally
            {
                network.Read(new byte[1], 0, 1);
                CloseTransfer();
            }
        }
    }
```

i should check for CancellationPending in the while() loop in send method .. but i can't get to [e.Cancel] of backgroundworker from this method .. what shall i do?

Comment: What's the problem to pass e as parameter from backgroundWorker1_DoWork to SendFile, then check in while loop after ReportProgress? You have also a finally clause to CloseTransfer

Comment: @Steve .. you mean like edit sendfile method to  :
void SendFile(string srcPath, string destPath, DoWorkEventArgs e)

Comment: Yes that's all Just add to SendFile a third argument

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The DoWorkEventArgs e could be passed as third argument in SendFile:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) 
{ 
    List<object> job = (List<object>)e.Argument; 
    string srcPath = (string)job[0]; 
    string destPath = (string)job[1]; 
    SendFile(srcPath, destPath, e); 
}
```

then SendFile will be

```
private void SendFile(string srcPath, string destPath, DoWorkEventArgs e)
```

and in your loop, after ReportProgress

```
   if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending == true)    
   {    
       e.Cancel = true;    
       return; // this will fall to the finally and close everything    
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Put it in your `while` loop:

```
while (sum < fileSize)
{
    if (worker.CancellationPending)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        break;
    }

    count = fs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    network.Write(data, 0, count);
    sum += count;
    sumAll += count;
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)((sum * 100) / fileSize));
}
network.Flush();
```

Comment: NOOO the important part is e.Cancel = true;

Comment: there's no e.Cancel !! should i pass the e from backgroundworker_dowork ?